# Checksum Issue while deploying nuget package by nuget command from powershell

Tags: nuget, artifactory

From powershell script I am using the nuget command to pack, sign , verify and push the artifact.

```
nuget sign $NugetFilePath -CertificatePath ".\$($ConfigInfo.ArtifactoryCredentials.CertificateFile)" -CertificatePassword $ConfigInfo.ArtifactoryCredentials.CertificatePassword
                           & nuget verify -All $NugetFilePath
                           & nuget push $NugetFilePath -Source $RepoKeyValue -SkipDuplicate -NonInteractive
```

With the above chain of nuget commands I get the nuget package deployed to the artifactory. Then to check it, I log into the Artifactory UI and see the following:

1. The package is uploaded.
2. Getting issue with the Checksum (Check the attached image)
   [image]

I can see in the console that the nuget sign does create the SH1A hash, SHA256 hash. But I do not know if it has anything to do with the Checksum complaint we are getting above.

Now If I deploy the very same nuget package manually with Artifactory UI, then the checksum complaint is not there anymore, wondering what is missed from the nuget command that created this checksum issue.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Some clients, for example Maven, are calculating a checksum before deploying an artifact and sending it to the repository. This allows to validate that the uploaded artifact is not corrupted or did not change for any other reason (for example Man-in-the-middle attack).
When you deploy from the Artifactory UI, the checksum is calculated and stored with the Artifact.
As an alternative, you can use the [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli/) for [deploying](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingNugetPackages) Nuget packages. The [benefits](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) of using the JFrog CLI includes parallel uploads/downloads and checksum optimizations.